# Detecting if an HTML element is scrolled beyond hidden overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with jQuery's scroll effect.

Scrolled elements are contained in an element with `overflow="hidden"`.

I need to activate some Javascript code once a portlet is scrolled to the view of the user, and other Javascript code to run when the portlet is hidden. I currently can't control the scroll buttons, so I had this idea: checking (periodically, with `window.setTimeout`) if the portlet is viewable or not by the user. Testing `visible="block"` won't help, obviously.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to compare via jQuery the element's `offset().left` with the container's `offset().left()` and `offset().left + width()` values.

I am assuming that all elements are sized in order to be either fully visible or invisible (so I just need to check left corner) **and** in my case scrolling is only horizontal, so no need to check top and height

Answer (score 4):

Look at the .scrollHeight property of the container. It will tell you the scroll position. Then compare that to the offset height of the element you're detecting.

Comment: I didn't mention that scrolling is horizontal. Do I then have to check scrollWidth VS offsetWidth?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I wrote a very small plugin for just this:

[jQuery Scrolled Out Of View](http://byrichardpowell.github.com/jquery-scrolled-out-of-view/)

It would be a little hard to post meaningful code examples here, so I suggest you check out the demo.

> Run it on an element, supply a wrapper element and an object will be
>   returned.  The object will have numerical values for top, bottom, left
>   and right if the element has been scrolled out of the wrapper on those
>   respective sides to represent by how many pixels the element is out of
>   view on that side.

I thought I would post here so that anyone landing from a Search would be able to find the plugin and perhaps save themselves some time.

Comment: I quitted that project long ago but you do definitely deserve an upvote for the effort.